# How to set field position when table height increses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I make a dynamic form when i click on add button one row add in a table but when i add more than 6 rows the table height covers fields,how i set this?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="table">
<table class="table table-bordered" style="border:1px solid white;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left; width:120px;">Item</th>
        <th style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Description</th>
        <th style="width:100px;">Unit Cost</th>
        <th style="text-align:right; width:60px;">Qty</th>
        <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Tax</th>
        <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Tax</th>
        <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Line Total</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>         
 <tr>        
 <td colspan=7 width=800>
 <div id="dataRows">
 <div class="fieldRow" id="template">
<select class="items" name="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" id="items"><option value="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option></select>
 <textarea name="description" id="description" class="description" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:211px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 0px 0;"></textarea>
 <input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice" class="unitprice" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 0px 0;">
 <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="quantity" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:64px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 0px 0;">
 <select name="firsttax" id="firsttax" class="firsttax" style=" float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected" ></option></select>
 <select name="secondtax" id="secondtax" class="secondtax" style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:104px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected"></option></select>
 <input type="text" name="linetotal" id="linetotal" class="linetotal" placeholder="0.00" readonly style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:104px; border-radius:0px; background-color: #F0F0F0; text-align:right; margin: -2px 0px 0;">   
<input type="button"  class="button remove"  id="btnDel" value="Remove Row" style="float:right; margin:0 -110px; color: #ffffff; background-color: #d9534f; border-color: #d43f3a; padding: 3px 10px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.428571429; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;  border:1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none;" />
 </div>
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <input type="hidden" id="itemscounter" name="itemscounter" value=""/>
 <tr>            
 <td colspan=7 rowspan=2 width=800 style="border:0px solid white;">
 <div style="border:1px solid #DDDDDD; width:317px; height:50px; margin:0 -1px; float:right;">
<label class="required" id="invoicetotal" for="Invoicetotal" style="padding-top:3px;">Invoice Total(USD)</label>
<span style=" font-weight:bold; margin:4px -204px 0; float:right;">$</span> 
<input type="text" class="required" id="invoicetotalamount" name="invoicetotalamount" placeholder="0.00" readonly style=" color:#526273; font-weight:bold; text-align:left; border: 0px solid #000000;"/><br>
<label class="required" id="paidtodate" for="paidtodate" style="margin-top: -6px;">Paid to date</label>
<input type="text" class="required" id="paidtodateamount" name="paidtodateamount" placeholder="0.00" style=" color:#526273; font-weight:bold; text-align:right; border: 0px solid #000000;"/>       
</div> 
<div class="clear"></div>
<div style="border:1px solid #DDDDDD; width:317px; height:33px; margin:50px -316px 0; float:right;">
<label class="required" id="balance" for="balance" style="margin-top:0px;">Balance(USD)</label> 
<span style=" font-weight:bold; margin:7px 45px 0; float:left;">$</span>    
<input type="text" class="required" id="balanceamount" name="balanceamount" placeholder="0.00" readonly style=" color:#526273; font-weight:bold; text-align:left; border: 0px solid #000000;"/> 
</div>   
 </td>       
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<label class="required" for="invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype_notes">Notes</label>
<input id="invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype_notes" type="text" maxlength="255" required="required" name="invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype[notes]">
```

and here is my css:

```
#table{
float: left;
height: 200px;
margin: -291px 19px 0;
width: 825px;
}

#invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype_notes{
margin-top:250px;
}
```

here is my error:

[image]

Comment: anybody who tell me when div height increases the field margin increases

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: no my code is too large

Comment: i attached a picture who give you idea of the problem plz see my question

Comment: Your picture just confuses me...

Comment: i attached new picture check

Comment: when i click add row button one row add in a table i want when table height increses then notes field automatically below the table

Comment: can you see picture again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notes input should normally follow the flow if more rows are added. Looks like a float clear issue.
Please see if adding to #table css

```
overflow:hidden;
```

helps.

If not you might need to add more height to the table in your jquery code on the "add handler". For that we need code though
But from the code you showed it more looks like the first

**UPDATE:**

Then try to clear your table float by wrapping a div around the input like this ( used inline style now, just for testing )

```
<div style="clear: left;">
<label class="required" for="invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype_notes">Notes</label>
<input id="invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype_notes" type="text" maxlength="255" required="required" name="invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype[notes]">
</div>
```

Comment: when i used overflow:hidden; my delete button not shown and also can't access the hidden fields of table

Comment: i used symfony2 i cannot attach inline css on notes

Comment: That html is full of inline css, if you cant use inline css, just give it an class instead and apply the clear left in the css. clear: right; on the #table might also work

Comment: @user2833510 well then there really isnt much we can do here. As a previous commenter pointed out already, thats where a preview to play with the code would come in handy. We dont know your javascript/jquery, and just a tiny potion of css